# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Error al actualizar discord.js 12v a 13v

Supuestamente en la libreria. Soy yo o no existe esa syntaxis en JavaScript?

```
D:\Proyectos\Discord\NombreDelProyecto\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\APIRequest.js:33
    agent ??= new https.Agent({ ...this.client.options.http.agent, keepAlive: true });
          ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ese operador **si existe** y su nombre es **Logical nullish assignment (??=)**.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment

Es compatible con nodeJS desde la versión 15.0, sugiero revises si tu versión es inferior a esa.

Saludos